# Node.js file server on Rpi3 Jesse

Tags: javascript

I have a file server that works perfectly on my Rpi 2 with Raspian and I have been trying to migrate it to a newer Rpi3 with Jesse.  Every time I try to run it I get the following error stack

```
/media/pi/DemoServer.js:82
server.listen(port, () => {
                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Any suggestions on why this is occurring?  Is there a subtle nuance between the two distributions that I should address?

Here is the code for the server (with some omissions).

```
const express     = require('express'); 
const formidable  = require('formidable');
const fs          = require('fs-extra');
const http        = require('http');
const util        = require('util');
const serveIndex  = require('serve-index');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const path        = require('path');
const server      = express();
const port        = process.env.PORT || 1001;
const dirToServe  = '/media/pi/Shared';

function setHeaders(res, filepath) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + path.basename(filepath));
}

server.post('/media/pi/Shared', function(req,res) {
});

//Serve the static folder and the index of the folder
server.use('/', serveIndex(dirToServe, { icond: true }));
server.use('/', serveStatic(dirToServe, {setHeaders: setHeaders }));

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Run `node -v` on each, it looks like you have an old version of Node running on the Rpi3.

Comment: @robertklep I think this may be the issue.  I will update and try again, thanks.